# Python sys.getrefcount() shows unexpected 4th reference

Tags: python, reference-counting

I'm looking for an explanation about why I have an unexpected reference count. Yes, I already know `sys.getrefcount()` will increment the expected count by `1`. That is not what's happening below.

I expect the function `test(a)` to show `3` not `4`. Where is the 4th reference coming from?

```
In [2]: import sys

In [3]: a = []

In [4]: sys.getrefcount( a )
Out[4]: 2

In [5]: def test( x ): print "x ref count = {}".format( sys.getrefcount( x ) )

In [6]: test( a )
x ref count = 4

In [7]: sys.getrefcount( a )
Out[7]: 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack is the 4th reference.

In order to send the value of `a` to the function, Python evaluates `a` first and puts the result on the top of the stack. That is a reference, just like the `x` variable in the `test()` function is a reference.

You can see this in the bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('test( a )', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (test)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

The [`CALL_FUNCTION` opcode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION) loads the arguments from the stack (the `1` here means *load 1 positional argument from the stack*) before invoking the object found *next* on the stack (the object referenced by `test`, put there by `LOAD_NAME`).

This is the exact same reason why the `sys.getrefcount()` call adds an extra reference; there too the object first has to be added to the stack before the function can be called.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: very informative, that's a great answer